# Apply formula to cells based on value in other column

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a dataframe with 10 columns and 60 rows.
The first 2 columns contain treatment size (sq. m) and observation time (min), the other 8 show the 8 observed species as count data. All are integers.
I want to apply a correction to the observations:

- Divide all observation counts by the root of the treatment size
- Divide all observation counts by the square root of the observation time

Probably easily done with `apply()` and `function()` but I am not very familiar... Anyone who could help?

Some exemplary code (just 2 species here):

```
dftot <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 60, ncol = 4))
colnames(dftot)<-  c("size", "time", "guppy", "barracuda")
set.seed(123)
dftot$size <- sample(60, size = 60, replace = TRUE)
dftot$time <- sample(60, size = 60, replace = TRUE)
dftot$guppy <- sample(60, size = 60, replace = TRUE)
dftot$barracuda <- sample(60, size = 60, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
dftot %>% 
  mutate(across(guppy:last_col(), ~.x/sqrt(size))) %>% 
  mutate(across(guppy:last_col(), ~.x/sqrt(time)))
```

Output:

```
   size time     guppy  barracuda
1    31   12 2.7997696 1.76281788
2    15   13 4.1534663 3.43735140
3    51   18 0.4950738 0.42906394
4    14   33 0.9770084 0.88396000
5     3   57 2.8294607 4.28242703
6    42   27 0.2375655 1.54417606
```

Comment: Thank you! THe only difference is that the real column names have no overlapping element in their name as with "species" in the exemplary code.. sorry about this missing detail.

Comment: I changed the example data

Comment: I change it accordingly, let me know if it works!